# How to handle NULL reference exception in c#?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a calculator app using Xamarin when the entry box is empty when calculate button is clicked it causes error and the app crashes how to handle it the numbers are of double type

Comment: try...catch maybe? Or even better just check for null

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: if you see any calculator, all entry box by default are 0, not empty, this will simply you a bit. to know if it is double try double.TryParse

Answer (score 4):

**Handle a Null Reference Exception.**

A NullReferenceException happens when you try to access a reference variable that isn’t referencing any object. If a reference variable isn’t referencing an object, then it’ll be treated as null. The run-time will tell you that you are trying to access an object, when the variable is null by issuing a NullReferenceException.

**Null Checks Try/Catch Blocks**

```
using System;

public class Example
{
/* set in the inspector*/
public Light myLight; 

public void Start () 
{
    try 
    {
        /* handle null Null ReferenceException*/
       if(myLight!=null) 
       {
         // here your code
       }
    }       
    catch (NullReferenceException ex) 
    {
        // handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are doing a string to a double? something like this:

```cs
double enteredNumberAsADouble;
string enteredNumberAsAString = "TestString";
if (double.TryParse(enteredNumberAsAString, out enteredNumberAsADouble))
{
    // Do stuff with enteredNumberAsADouble
}
```

`TryParse` -

> When this method returns, contains the double-precision floating-point number equivalent of the s parameter, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed. **The conversion fails if the s parameter is null or Empty, is not a number in a valid format, or represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue.** This parameter is passed uninitialized; any value originally supplied in result will be overwritten.

If this isn't the case then we will need you to update your question with more information or code.